# Generate duplicate rows in SELECT query (MySql)

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible in `SELECT * FROM` generate duplicate rows?

In some rows, I have a filed called quantity. When quantity is more than 1, I would like to duplicate that record.

```
example
    item    quantity
    book        1
    phone       3
    pencil      1
```

---

what I would like to get in recordset is

```
book
phone
phone
phone
pencil
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Just iterate though the results, and add additional records for each phone or whatever

Comment: Thank Dustytrash for yr answer
u mean add a for inside a while loop?

based on query is not possible?

Comment: It might be possible, but why do you need it in the query? And why did you tag PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a result for every 'quantity' e.g:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM books";

$originalResult = $conn->query($sql);
$modifiedResults = array();

while($row = $originalResult->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    array_push($modifiedResults, $row);

    for($i=0; $i< $row.quantity; $i++)
    {
        array_push($modifiedResults, $row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Possible solution is to use REPEAT

```
SELECT REPEAT(item, quantity) FROM <table_name> WHERE <condition>
```

and if you want in one string use GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(REPEAT(item1, quantity)) FROM <table_name> WHERE <condition>
```